# swift- how to open up calendar app at specific date and time?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, calendar

I can't find an accurate answer, but all I want to do is:

1. user clicks a button and passes in a date in miliseconds
2. my app opens the IOS default calendar app at that specific date and time.

I was using this code:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timeInMiliFromBackEnd/1000))
let interval = date.timeIntervalSince1970
let url = NSURL(string: "calshow:\(interval)")!
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
```

The calendar app opens, however it opens in some random year (January 2066 @ 3pm).

Can anyone provide the swift 3 code for this?

Cheers~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS Doesn't use `timeIntervalSince1970` as it's "epoch date." You should use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` instead:

```
//Convert the time from the server into a Date object
let seconds = TimeInterval(timeInMiliFromBackEnd/1000)
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)

//Convert the Date object into the number of seconds since the iOS "epoch date"
let interval = date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
if let url = URL(string: "calshow:\(interval)") {
  UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

(Code above updated to use newer `open(_:options:completionHandler:)` method, as opposed to the now-deprecated `openURL(_:)` method.)

Comment: I'm working with android as well and i store all my times from 1970, am i able to convert timeIntervalSince1970 to timeIntervialSinceReferenceDate?

Comment: @TheQ But you have a `Date` instance already so there's nothing to convert. Did you try using the code in this answer as-is?

Comment: @rmaddy So i updated my question and added 1 line of code `let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timeInMiliFromBackEnd/1000))` to maybe clear things up. I can't try the code as is, because @Duncan made a new date object. I got a timeInMili from a backend thats from in 1970 format and I need to be able to use that somehow to open a calendar, but its not opening to the correct date :(

Comment: @TheQ From the `Date` you create using `timeIntervalSince1970` you then access its `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`.

Comment: @rmaddy jeez i guess it worked, i feel dumb, no idea what code i was writing. thanks guys

Comment: sir could you please help to answer this question, it seems similar but I don't know how to add the title https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677145/how-to-open-create-event-screen-in-calendar-app-with-populated-data-in-swift

Comment: @DuncanC is there a way to open a month instead of a day view?